# Not loaded uicollectionview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Not loaded collectionview when I add in view did load:

```
newsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
newsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

but if delete this code, my collection load in cell.

this code for cell in tableview

```
class UserAddFriends: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var friendsCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var userPhoto: UIImageView!
let cellReuseIdentifier = "friendCell"
var listImageForFriendsCollection: [String]!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    friendsCollection.delegate = self
    friendsCollection.dataSource = self
    listImageForFriendsCollection = []
    userPhoto.circleImage()
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsCollectionView
    cell.friendsPhoto.image = UIImage(named: listImageForFriendsCollection[indexPath.row])
    cell.friendsPhoto.circleImage()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listImageForFriendsCollection.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code and your description lack context.

Looks to me as if you would like to display a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell.

If you set your UITableView's rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension you have to make sure that the content (i.e. your UICollectionView) inside the UITableViewCell determines the cell's height. You do this by adding the appropriate constraints, usually via Interface Builder.